# "Тот" или "тем" (оказался салат)?

Tags: падежи

> Шопский салат оказался зеленью с овощами и брынзой – **тот**, что мы
>   обычно называем греческим.

Comment: Как вариант: _**...тем салатом**, что мы обычно называем греческим._

Comment: А я бы написал "то", потому это местоимение относится скорее к зелени с прочим, чем к салату.

Comment: Я бы упростил: _Шопский салат оказался зеленью с овощами и брынзой – мы такой (обычно) называем "греческим"._ Кавычки здесь подчёркивают _условность_ наименования (мы употребляем это слово в качестве названия салата, а не просто говорим о его происхождении).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ОКАЗА́ТЬСЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), окажу́сь, ока́жешься; св. (несов. оказываться).
**4.** Предстать, явиться на деле, в действительности **каким-либо, кем-либо, чем-либо.**
*Оказаться подлецом. Оказаться автором многочисленных изобретений. История оказалась выдумкой. Оформить документы оказалось проблемой. Путь оказался тяжёлым. Требования оказались высокими. Телефон оказался занятым.*

Шопский салат оказался (чем?) зеленью с овощами и брынзой — (чем?) тем, что мы обычно называем греческим салатом. [Добавляем "салатом" — во избежание смешения родов.]

Можно так:
**Шопский салат оказался зеленью с овощами и брынзой — таким, который мы обычно называем греческим.**
Или так:
Шопский салат — зелень с овощами и брынзой — оказался тем, что мы обычно называем греческим салатом.